# wysiwyg preview?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, preview

I am looking to use a wysiwyg javascript editor.

What I want to do is have the ability for the user to click preview and have the content (including images) be previewed in an actual page.

Are there any editors that support this?

Comment: preview option is always there in many editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), formerly called FCKEditor. It has got a preview button. The built-in plugins allow you to upload and browse images as well (this part needs a little configuration).

Answer (score 2):

Read below article

[25-wysiwyg-editors-reviewed](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/05/06/25-wysiwyg-editors-reviewed/)

**Note :** I personally prefer  [`nicEdit`](http://nicedit.com/)

Comment: Ah very useful link mr Keshav Mohta :)

Comment: @Hailwood Thanks for calling me by my name :)

Comment: The link is useful, But im not looking for a wysiwyg code editor, Im building a system like wordpress. so I need something like tinymce, but want a editor that has the ability to add a preview link which simply sends the content as a parameter to the page...

Comment: i think `nicEdit` will b helpful for your need